# Bootstrap: Cannot properly separate button from panel-body

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and Html. I am currently trying to separate my **Add Person button** away from the panel body but I do not know how to achieve that. Below is the **screenshot** of my problem and my **current codes**:

[image: screenshot]

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Manage Person
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Persons" class="btn btn-primary btn-group-sm">
        Add Person
    </a>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Height</th>                    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rachel</td>
                        <td>25</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td>175cm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Thomas</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td>165cm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jared</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td>195cm</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma Bootstrap 3

Comment: Ok. Check my answer now then. Updated it as per bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clearfix` div as sugggested below. And add `margin-top: 10px;` on the `panel-body`

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading ">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Manage Person
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group pull-right" style="float: right;">
    <a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Persons" class="btn btn-primary btn-group-sm">
        Add Person
    </a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="panel-body" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Height</th>                    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rachel</td>
                        <td>25</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td>175cm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Thomas</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td>165cm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jared</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                        <td>195cm</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Nandita, may I know why you replace the position of the .clearfix class?

Comment: this is one of the correct ways to use clearfix class. the way you used was probably wrong. I mostly use it the way i mentioned in the answer. So i know that it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <a asp-action="Create" style="margin-bottom:5px" asp-controller="Persons" class="btn btn-primary btn-group-sm">
        Add Person
    </a>
</div>
```

you can use margin-bottom.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my way to fix this:

- Give your button an id and add bottom margin within your css:
  `#yourButtonId{ margin-bottom: 10px; }`

OR

- Put your Button in a new bootstrap row: `<div class="row"> ---Your button code--- </div>`